# If $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime integers then prove that ($a$ ,$b^2$) =1

Tags: number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

From the title I've stucked in this question for half an hour. Could anyone help me?

Comment: All the prime factors of `bb` are the same as `b`.

Comment: I've written the linear sum of (a,b)=1 that was ax+by=1 and ap+b^2q =1 ,and I've multiplied the equation ax+by=1 with b then it was abx+b^2y = b .

Comment: Relatively prime means they have no common factors which means they have no common prime factors.  Does $b^2$ have any other prime factors than $b$ doesn't?

Comment: OMG I asked you wrong actually it was "Proove that (a,b^2)=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have 
$$
(a,b)=1 \iff  ax+by=1 \text{   for  some integer $x,y$} 
$$
Then 
$$
(ax+by)^2=1 \implies a(ax^2+2bxy)+b^2 y^2=1 \implies (a,b^2)=1.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much :) :) :)

Answer (score 3):

Consider the prime factors of $a$ and those of $b$. The fact that $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime means that $a$ and $b$ have no common prime factors. But then $a$ and $b^2$ have no common prime factors either; that is, $a$ and $b^2$ are relatively prime. QED.

(We have used the observation that $b^2$ has the same prime factors as $b$, with each prime factor in $b^2$ repeated twice as many times as in $b$.)

Answer (score 2):

If some integer $d$ divides $b$, then we can write $b = dx$ for some $x \in \mathbb{Z}$.  From this, we have $b^2 = (dx)^2 = d(dx^2)$, so $d$ also divides $b^2$.

Now look back to the definition for $\gcd$.  What if $d|a$ **and** $d|b^2$ wherein $d \neq 1$?

Comment: Thank you  very much :) :) :)

Comment: Oh, of course! You're showing the contrapositive. Thanks for clarifying, and sorry for my slowness. I'll delete my original comment.

Comment: No problem @AlexWertheim.  Certainly a valid concern to have at first glance.

Answer (score 0):

Proof by contraposition.

Let $d:= \gcd (a,b^{2}) \geq 2$. Then $d \mid a$ and $d \mid b^{2}$. Note that $d \mid b^{2}$ implies $\gcd (d, b) \geq 2$. So $\gcd (a,b) \geq 2$.